# Node.js HTTP client with HTML

Tags: html, node.js, http, esp8266

I have a simple web server on my ESP8266 and I'm able to communicate with it with my Node.js HTTP client and sending commands on terminal only. I want to connect an HTML webpage to my Node.js HTTP client so that I can use a slider on the web page and send values accordingly. how can I do that? I didnt see any single example over the internet for doing this,

Comment: Your ESP8266 serves webpage when receiving a request from a client. So you need to create a html webpage and have the esp8266 to serve it upon request. To write a html page with a slider has nothing to do with ESP8266 or Arduino. There are plenty of examples on the web if you know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a lot of code to do that. You will need a library for http requests like axios or node.js built-in http.request. After that you add a web server (Express or fastify or uWebSockets), add an html page and POST/GET request processing, which will send through axios (or http.request) command to the ESP8266 itself.

If interested, I could do that if I wasn't busy. Only I need more information about the commands the ESP8266 executes and what you have already written. But I'm busy anyway!